How to set the start date of the workweek for a month using Python?
I have a database with a date column in the following format:

However, I need to work with this database so that it can be recognized as a time series. In this case, the names "week 1", "week 2", "week 3", and "week 4" should be replaced with dates. If we know that each week has 7 days, each of the weeks in the month would start on the first business day of that month, and the next week would be 7 days later. Is it possible to do this with Python?
For example, in the month of June 2024, the first business day was the 3rd. So,
week 1 = 06/03/2024
week 2 = 06/10/2024
week 3 = 06/17/2024
week 4 = 06/24/2024

And so on, each month would have its own specificity and start date. Is it possible to do this with Python and then obtain a weekly frequency of business days?

Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like code formatting or table formatting.

It is possible, of course, but what's the initial date? Can you please explain a bit more?

I see you tagged this with [[tag:dataframe]] but you haven't mentioned any details. Are you using Pandas? Have you read the user guide related to this? Time series / date functionality. I think § DateOffset objects is the most relevant.

Do you need to account for holidays?

@MarkRansom If it's easier to continue without the holidays, I can ignore them.

@LukeL The start date is January 2022 and the end date is June 2024. The base is fine as the photo shows. jun 24 represents the information at monthly granularity and the weeks below correspond to the same month, but at week granularity. I would like to read these weeks as dates

Python's datetime provides a numeric weekday, so you just need to add the missing days to the next monday (in case the first day is on a weekend):
import datetime as dt

def first_business_day(year, month):
    # Start with the first day of the month and it's weekday (0=Monday, 6=Sunday)
    first_day = dt.datetime(year, month, 1)
    first_weekday = first_day.weekday()

    for i, weekday in enumerate([5,6]): # Add days to next monday for sat/sun
        if first_weekday == weekday:
            first_day += dt.timedelta(days=2-i)
    # returns 4 weeks based on the first business day!
    return list(first_day + dt.timedelta(days=x*7) for x in range(0, 4))

for m in range(1, 13):
    first_business_day_weeks = first_business_day(2024, m)
    print("first_business_day_weeks:", [x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for x in first_business_day_weeks])

Out:
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-01-01', '2024-01-08', '2024-01-15', '2024-01-22']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-02-01', '2024-02-08', '2024-02-15', '2024-02-22']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-03-01', '2024-03-08', '2024-03-15', '2024-03-22']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-04-01', '2024-04-08', '2024-04-15', '2024-04-22']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-05-01', '2024-05-08', '2024-05-15', '2024-05-22']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-06-03', '2024-06-10', '2024-06-17', '2024-06-24']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-07-01', '2024-07-08', '2024-07-15', '2024-07-22']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-08-01', '2024-08-08', '2024-08-15', '2024-08-22']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-09-02', '2024-09-09', '2024-09-16', '2024-09-23']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-10-01', '2024-10-08', '2024-10-15', '2024-10-22']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-11-01', '2024-11-08', '2024-11-15', '2024-11-22']
first_business_day_weeks: ['2024-12-02', '2024-12-09', '2024-12-16', '2024-12-23']

Note: In case you need a pandas solution, have a look at: First Business Date of Month Python

Ignoring holidays:
import datetime
months={'jan':1, 'feb':2, 'mar':3, 'apr':4, 'may':5, 'jun':6, 'jul':7, 'aug':8, 'sep':9, 'oct':10, 'nov':11, 'dec':12}
def first_weekday(month, year):
    if year < 100:
        year += 2000
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)
    weekday = dt.weekday() # 0=monday, 6=sunday
    offset = 0 if weekday < 5 else 7 - weekday
    return dt + datetime.timedelta(days=offset)

date_str = 'jun/24'
month_str,year_str = date_str.split('/')
first_weekday(months[month_str], int(year_str))
# datetime.datetime(2024, 6, 3, 0, 0)

That will give you the first weekday of any month.  Then for the rest you can just add datetime.timedelta(weeks=week-1).
